# Popup при ошибке ввода данных (input)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, input

Собственно, пример для вопроса:

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
   
input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type='number']:valid {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

input[type='number']:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" step="5">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Если ввести значение не кратное пяти и нажать submit, то выпадет такой popup (в хроме):
[image: Input error popup]

Так вот, сам вопрос заключается в том, как изменить внешний вид этого сообщения. Желательно через CSS, без использования скрипта, если, конечно, это возможно.

Comment: Нет, это не возможно. В каждого браузера свой такой причуд.. Но можно изменить текст внутри..

Comment: @Cactus , про текст я в курсе. `data-errormessage-value-missing` и `data-errormessage-type-mismatch`. И по поводу того, что у каждого браузера свои причуды, тоже очень даже в курсе. :) Но всё же. Это же стандартная фишка с popup сообщениями на ошибках инпута. Что, никак нельзя повлиять на неё? А если таки с JS? Какой-нибудь ивент onerror? Типа задать `event.preventDefault()` и вызывать фиксированное окошко на инпуте с нужными данными и, главное, оформлением. Ну, раз уж чистым css нет возможности этого сделать.

Comment: С помощью js естественно можно создать что-то вроде `tooltip`, как в `4 bootstrap`. Вот: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: @Cactus , добро, благодарю. Жаль, конечно, что только таким образом. :)

Comment: Вот нашел пример на css: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip :D

Comment: @Cactus , хм... Немного не то, но интересно. Типа сделать под `:invalid` элементами `:before` и `:after` что ли. Хотя всё равно без JS будет так-же вылазить и стандартный popup, под этим или перекрывая его. Но с этим можно работать. Ещё раз благодарю. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Я уверен, что какой нибудь костыльный способ на чистом **css** всегда можно отыскать, но нужно ли оно...? 

        Сделал для Вас пример на чистом **js** с объяснением. Пытался донести гибкий способ решения проблемы, надеюсь получилось :)


        

    
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn'); //находим кнопку

function validateInput() { //создаем функцию проверки инпута
  var input = document.querySelector('.number');   // находим инпут и записываем в переменную  
  var inputStep = input.getAttribute('data');    //находим атрибут data в который записан шаг, будем использовать его в условии, что бы не лезть в js, если поменяем шаг
  var error = document.querySelector('.error');  //находим span error

  if (input.value % inputStep !== 0 || input.value == 0 || input.value == '') {           // делаем проверку, если значение в инпуте не делится нацело на значение шага или равно 0 или пустой строке
    error.classList.add('error_state_active');   // то на элемент error вешаем класс с display block
    return false;
  } else {
    error.classList.remove('error_state_active'); // иначе удаляем класс
    return true;
  }
};

function submitForm() {
    var form = document.querySelector('.form');   // находим форму
    if (validateInput()) {
      form.submit(); // отправляем форму
    }    
};

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие по умолчанию
  validateInput(); //вызываем функцию проверки инпута
  submitForm();
});
    
        
    
    form {
          position: relative;
        }
    
    .number {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .error {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 130px;
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .error_state_active {
      display: block;
    }
 
        
  

      <form class="form">
          <input type="number" data="5" class="number">
          <span class="error">Error</span>
          <input type="submit" class="btn">
        </form>
```

Comment: **убирает проверку формы**. Ага, и таким образом пропускаем абсолютно любые введенные данные...

Comment: @Cheg, это же не очень критично, т.к. на сервере в любом случае проверяют входные данные, ведь так? Или я ошибаюсь очень сильно?

Comment: @Cactus и для чего же тогда вообще нужна эта html/js проверка?

Comment: @Cheg, разве не для удобства пользователя? Конечно не каждый будет лезть в исходный код, ноо.. :) Прислушаюсь к вашим советам.

Comment: @Cactus о каком удобстве может идти речь, если посетитель может отправить абсолютно любые данные, но при этом никакого результата не получит, когда сервер получит некорректные данные, проверит их и проигнорирует?

Comment: @Cheg, хмм, действительно.